# Android ExoPlayer can not display

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Hi I want to display video in exo player . on link I have basic authorize a link look like : http://login:pass@xxx.xxx.x.xxx:port/...

this is how I init a exo player :

```
private fun initializePlayer() {
    if (player == null) {
        val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(this)
        trackSelector.setParameters(
            trackSelector.buildUponParameters().setMaxVideoSizeSd())
        player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this)
            .setTrackSelector(trackSelector)
            .build()
    }
    playerView!!.player = player
    videoViewModel.videoUrlList.forEach {
        val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoViewModel.getMedia(it)!!)
        player!!.addMediaItem(mediaItem)
    }

    player!!.playWhenReady = videoViewModel.videoStarted

    player!!.seekTo(videoViewModel.currentVideoIndex,
        videoViewModel.currentVideoPosition.toLong())

    player!!.addListener(this)
    player!!.addAnalyticsListener(this)
    player!!.prepare()
}
```

And in log I have      `Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 401`

this url works correct in webView

```
   fun getMedia(mediaName: String): Uri? {
        return if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(mediaName))
            Uri.parse(mediaName)
        else
            null
    }
```

Comment: The error 401 means that you do not have permission to access this content. Are you sure when you are calling `videoViewModel.getMedia(it)!!` it is returning a proper URL with `login` and `pass`

Comment: @che10 yes Im a sure, this url works corretly when I load in WEbView

Comment: I would suggest one thing for you to debug it, when you are setting the `MediaItem` and you get the required URL from this call `videoViewModel.getMedia(it)!!`. Just try doing this once and see if it is working. Just do it on the first item as follows. 

`videoViewModel.getMedia(videoViewModel.videoUrlList.first())`

Comment: @che10 I try do this but still I have com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 401

Comment: No, what I meant was try opening a WebView from there and see if it is working. As in open a webView from what you get via `videoViewModel.getMedia(videoViewModel.videoUrlList.first())`

Comment: @che10 no I open like this :   webView.loadUrl(url) where url is a string

Comment: Yes, and what does `videoViewModel.getMedia(videoViewModel.videoUrlList.first())` returns? Is that not also a string? That is what I am asking you to debug, if the URL we are getting is proper and if we do 
`webView.loadUrl(videoViewModel.getMedia(videoViewModel.videoUrlList.first()))` we should get to know what is wrong.

Comment: @che10 I edit my post and I put this method

Comment: @che10 this method return Uri

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share a sample URL? Unless the method is returning `null` there is no reason for it not to work in `ExoPlayer`.

Comment: @che10 it works only from my wifi , this methot is not returning null

Comment: Okay. This is a long shot, but there is nothing wrong with your code. But please check your port configuration of your device on which you are testing. I am assuming it is some sort of local server. In android your url is http, so http protocol is assumed. However on PC or your wifi I have no idea what is being done.

Comment: @che10 a port is not a probleme, exo player return me 401 Unauthorized

Comment: I would suggest you try running your URL once in [VLC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc&hl=en_IE&gl=US) and see if it is working. I still believe it is some sort of port issue.

Comment: @che10 I can not open this stream on this aplication

Comment: Then there is some issue with the URL only and something related to how the local network is configured. Your code is okay. `WebView` is a different aspect as compared to streaming via URL.

Comment: @che10 what I should to do ?

Comment: There is no answer as such. You can try some things out. I would suggest you once search up on how to configure emulator to local port and try running your app in emulator and check once there. I am assuming you are using a physical device for now. That should confirm you further if the issue is with how the network is considered. Also take a look [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/7668). This might or might not help.